# Изменение цвета текста активного пункта в NavigationView

Tags: android, меню, android-navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-navigation-view

Немного тупой вопрос... Имею Drawer заданный через xml с помощью DrawerLayout. Сам дравер заполняю через menu-res. Как изменить цвет текста выделенного пункта? Именно цвет текста, а не фон.

[image: Сейчас так]

Пробовал поменять параметр `android:textColorPrimary` в `styles.xml`, но он окрашивает все пункты меню. Выделенный пункт все так же чёрного цвета.

[image: как изменить цвет правильно?]

На этом сайте находил только пример изменения цвета фона в дровере с ListView, мне он не подходит.
Вроде бы такая простая задача, а решить не могу.

Comment: Таки у вас там NavigationView или ListView?

Comment: NavigationView. Юзаю стандартный шаблон из Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте файл `navigation_view_selector.xml` в `res/color`
2. Задайте там нужные цвета для нужных состояний

   ```
   <selector
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:color="#724646" android:state_checked="true"/>
       <item android:color="#724646" android:state_pressed="true"/>
       <item android:color="#724646"/>

   </selector>
   ```
3. В разметке задайте этот селектор для `NavigationView`

   ```
   app:itemIconTint="?navigationViewItemIconColor"
   app:itemTextColor="?navigationViewItemTextColor"
   ```
4. Также кое что можно через стили задать

   ```
    <style name="navigationStyle" parent="SCP.Theme.Light">
       <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ff0000</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">#00ff00</item>
   </style>
   ```

   который также можно задать в размтке

   ```
   style="@style/navigationStyle"
   ```